Fail to start mysql docker container in Mac
I try to start mysql docker container in Mac, but hit the following error, I already tried to redownload images and even reinstall docker desktop, but still doesn't work. Does anyone know what's wrong here? Thanks
2024-11-05 17:40:10 2024-11-05T09:40:10.807036Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2024-11-05 17:40:11 2024-11-05T09:40:11.775220Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2024-11-05 17:40:11 2024-11-05T09:40:11.984363Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013183] [InnoDB] Assertion failure: fut0lst.ic:81:addr.page == FIL_NULL || addr.boffset >= FIL_PAGE_DATA thread 140642114078464
2024-11-05 17:40:11 InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
2024-11-05 17:40:11 InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
2024-11-05 17:40:11 InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
2024-11-05 17:40:11 InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
2024-11-05 17:40:11 InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
2024-11-05 17:40:11 InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
2024-11-05 17:40:11 InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
2024-11-05 17:40:11 2024-11-05T09:40:11Z UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
2024-11-05 17:40:11 Most likely, you have hit a bug, but this error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
2024-11-05 17:40:11 BuildID[sha1]=6b049f17400f850658b2eb3ff165ec9a085d9655
2024-11-05 17:40:11 Thread pointer: 0x7fe978000b60
2024-11-05 17:40:11 Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
2024-11-05 17:40:11 where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
2024-11-05 17:40:11 terribly wrong...
2024-11-05 17:40:11 stack_bottom = 7fe9cb3ffb10 thread_stack 0x100000
2024-11-05 17:40:11 /usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace(unsigned char const*, unsigned long)+0x41) [0x213de91]
2024-11-05 17:40:11 /usr/sbin/mysqld(print_fatal_signal(int)+0x387) [0xfdeac7]
2024-11-05 17:40:11 /usr/sbin/mysqld(my_server_abort()+0x7e) [0xfdec1e]
2024-11-05 17:40:11 /usr/sbin/mysqld(my_abort()+0xe) [0x2137c7e]
2024-11-05 17:40:11 /usr/sbin/mysqld(ut_dbg_assertion_failed(char const*, char const*, unsigned long)+0x33a) [0x243b28a]
2024-11-05 17:40:11 /usr/sbin/mysqld() [0x2408158]
2024-11-05 17:40:11 /usr/sbin/mysqld() [0x2408d44]
2024-11-05 17:40:11 /usr/sbin/mysqld(trx_purge(unsigned long, unsigned long, bool)+0xeb) [0x240ba6b]
2024-11-05 17:40:11 /usr/sbin/mysqld(srv_purge_coordinator_thread()+0x4c2) [0x23de3d2]
2024-11-05 17:40:11 /usr/sbin/mysqld(void Detached_thread::operator()<void (*)()>(void (*&&)())+0xca) [0x22fd0fa]
2024-11-05 17:40:11 /lib64/libstdc++.so.6(+0xc2ba3) [0x7fea0d2c2ba3]
2024-11-05 17:40:11 /lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x81da) [0x7fea0ec081da]
2024-11-05 17:40:11 /lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x43) [0x7fea0c639e73]
2024-11-05 17:40:11 
2024-11-05 17:40:11 Trying to get some variables.
2024-11-05 17:40:11 Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
2024-11-05 17:40:11 Query (0): is an invalid pointer
2024-11-05 17:40:11 Connection ID (thread ID): 0
2024-11-05 17:40:11 Status: NOT_KILLED
2024-11-05 17:40:11 
2024-11-05 17:40:11 The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
2024-11-05 17:40:11 information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.


File corruption on your Mac.

@GregAskew how to fix that? I have tried to reinstall docker-desktop and redownload images.

I have tried the mac disk utility first-aid, but doesn't work.
